# I want to clear the markers in my map when each time location changes instead of clearing the map itself

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio

I want just the markers in the map to be cleared whenever the location changes, instead of clearing the whole map. For instance if i use mMap.clear() in my code, the whole map refreshes and i am not able to look anywhere else in the map. As soon as i am trying to look somewhere else, the whole map clears whenever the location is changed.

The method provided named as updateMap() is called in the overridden method onLocationChanged of LocationListener and the parameter provided is the location of the Location class's object.

``````````````````````````
 public void updateMap(Location location){
     mMap.clear();
     LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title.("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(Bit`````````````````````````mapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15f));
}
``````````````````````````

I expect the output in which the user can look anywhere on the map even if the location of the user keeps changing instead of the map refreshing every time mMap.clear() line of code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your marker on a datatype Marker.

```
Marker markerName = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Title"));
```

and you can remove it like this.

```
markerName.remove();
```